# How to perform authorization to container engine REST API to get clusters data?

Tags: rest, oauth, google-oauth, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I want access container engine REST API's given here - 
http://kubernetes.io/third_party/swagger-ui/#/

To access above given API's, I did following-

1) I have created container cluster with project Id - virtual-cycling-11111 with zone- us-central1 and  API name - serverconfig

2) I created OAuth2.0 client Id and secret key.
I am using following method to generate access token:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d' {
    "client_id": "757054420263-09g36ip2jdt6kcl6cvlfl17faaaaaaa.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "client_secret": "NyZ0YwvEQAMaeNTD4dfgtht",
    "refresh_token": "1/6BMfW9j53gdGIasdfUH5kU5RsR4zwI9lUVX-tqf8JXQ",
    "grant_type": "refresh_token"
} ' https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token
```

How do generate access token and use it to access REST API?
Also can I use this in browser to get output?

Answer (score 1):

Google has developer documentation for using [OAuth 2.0 to Access Google  APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) (and the Google Container Engine is one such API). It explains the various authentication flows and how to get access tokens.